# Import MSI antenna file into a custom antenna element

Tags: matlab

Hello i've downloaded a correct MSI radiation pattern file. I've imported it using MSI read, i'm able to visualize to azimuth and elevation cut patterns.

I want to use its radiation pattern and create a custom antenna element using phased.CustomAntennaElement

the issue is when i try using phased.CustomAntennaElement arguments  'HorizontalMagnitudePattern', and 'VerticalMagnitudePattern' i get a size error since the vertical and horizontal magnitute patterns ive imported from the msi files have 360x1 size instead the arguments of the custom antenna expects 181x361?

> ```
> Error using phased.internal.AbstractElement (line 25)
> Expected HorizontalMagnitudePattern to be of size 181x361, but it is of size 360x1.
> ```

here is my code

```
clear;clc;
azang = [-180:180];
elang = [-90:90];
[Horizontal,Vertical,Optional] = msiread('Kathrein\80010652_2655_x_co_p45_08t_rs.msi');
phasepattern = zeros(361);
antena = phased.CustomAntennaElement('AzimuthAngles',azang, ...
    'ElevationAngles',elang,'SpecifyPolarizationPattern',true,...
    'HorizontalMagnitudePattern', Horizontal.Magnitude, ...
    'VerticalMagnitudePattern',Vertical.Magnitude,'PhasePattern',phasepattern);
pattern(antena,2.655e9,[-180:180],[-180:180],'CoordinateSystem',...
    'Polar','Type','powerdb')
```

Comment: no one?? i need help!